# CMAKe library level CFLAGS

Tags: cmake

I have project of following struct

```
 A 
   CMakeLists.txt
 B 
   CMakeLists.txt
 C
   CMakeLists.txt
```

I directory level CFLAGS .

so what CFLAGS A uses to compile will be only used for A only.

How can I set directory level or (sub project level ) CFLAGS using cmake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do following:

```
set_source_files_properties(file1.c file2.c
    PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS ${YOUR_CFLAGS_HERE}
)
```

Still, it's recommended to use add_definitions(), include_directories(), link_directories() and so on.

if any of these functions will be called in A/CMakeLists.txt, they will not have any effect on {B,C}/CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: this is per file CFLAGS, what about per-project CFLAGS ?